# How to get this noisy fog or skies effect with a gradient texture in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, texture

I really wanted to get this kind of foggy sort of glowing texture, with also the noise. And it seems it got a little bit of gradient in it's side. I've been tweaking the gradient maps with noise effect and couldn't seem to get that look. I've been trying to edit a layer that consists of fog textures from a brush I've downloaded and edit them using noise effect. can't seem to pull it off either.

[image]

Also I've been wanting trying to get this texture from the night skies. It seems the composition of the stars is based out of the noise effect and gradients too, how can I get these results?

[image]

Is it the blending mode that needs to be tweaked? I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for anyone out there that is answering, really big help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways here im adding white noise pixels to the image below

1. Make a new layer called noise

   2. Fill it with gray
2. Make s second layer above that scales the noise on top

   1. put a gradient on this layer (put a linear gradient form black to white to estimate good values for the noise level)
   2. Set mode of this layer to hard mix
3. Select the noise layer

   1. Use **filter-> noise > Add noise...**. Or use a grunge texture
   2. Set mode to monochrome
   3. Set amount to 5-50%
   4. *Optional* scale the noise layer to get bigger grained noise.
4. You can paint the noise density with a brush or any other graduated image in the hard mix layer
5. multiply this in over the rest of the artwork
6. *Optional* use a gradient map to colorize a copy of the gradient layer and multiply it a top of your stack.

[image]

Image 1: Very quickly (and badly) done example showing the outlined method. I did some slight burning on the black & white 1 layer to controll the lighness of the skin. Stock image from [Faestock](http://faestock.deviantart.com/). Lot could be done to the image to make the effect better.